# Unable to update values to database in PHP and MySQL

Tags: php, mysql

I am trying to update the value to database, but one way or an another i am not able to.

**Code:**

```
<?php

include 'init.php';

$dataid = $_POST['data_id'];


if(isset($dataid))
{

    /*user connects to database and performs some operation here*/

    /* values from database is returned and user passes the same to below function */

    calculateamount($kk_data_id,$kk_egg,$kk_cash,$kk_in,$kk_out,$kk_expenditure,$kk_cashout,$kk_wholesale1,$kk_wholesale2,$kk_wholesale3,$kk_touch,$kk_galtha,$kk_kotla,$wholesale_1,$wholesale_2,$wholesale_3,$touch,$galtha,$kotla,$retail,$prevegg,$prevcash);

}

function calculateamount($kk_data_id,$kk_egg,$kk_cash,$kk_in,$kk_out,$kk_expenditure,$kk_cashout,$kk_wholesale1,$kk_wholesale2,$kk_wholesale3,$kk_touch,$kk_galtha,$kk_kotla,$rwholesale_1,$rwholesale_2,$rwholesale_3,$rtouch,$rgaltha,$rkotla,$rretail,,$prevegg,$prevcash)
{
    /*performs Mathematical operations
    with data retrieved and passes the final values to the below function to update to database*/

    //ALL THE VALUES ARE CONVERTED TO STRING BEFORE PASSING ON TO THE BELOW FUNCTION

    updatevaluestodatabase($finalwhl1amount,$finalwhl2amount,$finalwhl3amount,$finaltchamount,$finalgalamount,$finalkotamount,$finalretailval,$finalretamount,$finaltotamount,
                           $finaltottally);

}

function updatevaluestodatabase($finalwhl1amount,$finalwhl2amount,$finalwhl3amount,$finaltchamount,$finalgalamount,$finalkotamount,$finalretailval,$finalretamount,$finaltotamount,
                                $finaltottally)
{
    $updatedata = "UPDATE kk_data SET wholesale1_amt=?,wholesale2_amt=?,wholesale3_amt=?,touch_amt=?,galtha_amt=?,kotla_amt=?,
                    kk_retail=?,retail_amt=?,kk_total_amount=?,kk_final_tally=? where kk_data_id = ?";
    $updatestmt = mysqli_prepare($con, $updatedata);
    mysqli_stmt_bind_param($updatestmt, sssssssssss,$finalwhl1amount,$finalwhl2amount,$finalwhl3amount,$finaltchamount,$finalgalamount,$finalkotamount,$finalretailval,$finalretamount,
                           $finaltotamount,$finaltottally,$dataid);
    mysqli_stmt_execute($updatestmt);
    mysqli_stmt_store_result($updatestmt);

    $response = array();
    $response["success"] = false;

    if(mysqli_stmt_affected_rows($updatestmt) > 0 )
    {
        $response["success"] = true;
    }

header('Content-Type: application/json');
echo json_encode($response);

}

?>
```

**OUTPUT**
Every time I run the below script in postman `('data_id' = value)` or through application:

> $response["success"] = false;

is returned always . Data is not updated to the database.

**What I tried**

Instead of using  `mysqli_stmt_affected_rows($updatestmt)` I tried executing using `mysqli_stmt_execute($updatestmt);` in the `if` statement. But no luck there

I am unable to figure out where the issue is or if am incorrect in calling the function.

NOTE: I thought I would post a minimized code to avoid clumsiness.

Comment: `sssssssssss` should be quoted. You should have a value in your function call `$rretail,,$prevegg`, maybe `''` (single quotes).

Comment: @chris85 : Thats so stupid of me. Thanks much. I reviewed my code but dont know how i missed it. Thanks much.  I acutally added ssss within quotes but not sure how it not copied here.. I fixed the function and its working now. Thanks much again

Comment: You should enable/use error reporting in the future. This error is reported when you run this code, https://3v4l.org/tDN1K. `Parse error: syntax error, unexpected ',', expecting variable (T_VARIABLE) in /in/tDN1K on line 19` Since this is a typo and not a programming issue I'd recommended deleting the question.